# What did Japan do during the Siberian expedition to insure the creation of a buffer state or acquire territory?

Tags: japan, siberia

> Japan's motives in the Siberian Intervention were complex and poorly
> articulated. Overtly, Japan (as with the United States and the other
> international coalition forces) was in Siberia to safeguard stockpiled
> military supplies and to rescue the Czechoslovak Legion. However, the
> Japanese government's antipathy to communism and socialism, a
> determination to recoup historical losses to Russia, **and the perceived
> opportunity to settle the "northern problem" to Japan's advantage by
> either creating a buffer state[7] or through outright territorial
> acquisition were also factors.**

What did Japan do during the Siberian expedition to insure the creation of a buffer state?

> However, patronage of various White movement leaders left Japan in a
> poor diplomatic position vis-à-vis the government of the Soviet Union,
> after the Red Army eventually emerged victorious from the Russian
> Civil War. The intervention tore Japan's wartime unity to shreds,
> leading to the army and government being involved in bitter
> controversy, as well as renewed factional strife in the army itself.

It's heavily implied that they did this by planning to give the territory to the White movement leaders, but there's no mention of Japan trying to do this by territorial acquisition.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siberian_intervention

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_intervention_in_Siberia

> Japan would later occupy part of Siberia during the Russian Civil War,
> going as far west as Lake Baikal. The occupation, however, was
> hideously costly, and following the collapse of **all credible White
> allies in the region, defense against the well-organized Red Army
> started proving increasingly difficult. Eventually, the occupation
> became exceedingly unpopular on the home front and a popular target
> for criticism by the Japanese Diet.[3]** The Japanese occupation of
> Siberia devolved into a boondoggle within four years - much as the
> Soviet occupation of Afghanistan or the US intervention in Vietnam
> would later in the century - and eventually, the Japanese saw fit to
> cut their losses.

https://www.quora.com/Why-didnt-the-U-S-allow-Japan-to-annex-Siberia-after-winning-the-war-against-Russia-even-though-the-U-S-was-not-allied-with-Japan

I could not find any citation saying that Japan tried to annex Siberian territory during or after the Siberian expedition.

Comment: Seems to me that occupation is a prelude to annexation... is there a reason you're discarding this?

Comment: Please, make clear the sources of your citations, for instance, what's the source of the 1st paragraph, is it the one listed immediately after? The part "a determination to recoup historical losses to Russia" sounds utterly wrong to me. As for "buffer states", there were several: First the "white buffer", then it split into "red" and "white" buffers. But, eventually, the "red" buffer (effectively, under Soviet command and aided by Soviet troops) defeated the "white" one (in 1922). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_Eastern_Republic